# iteration variable inside for changing its value

Tags: php

I'm facing something I don't understand, I've tried many things. The weird thing is that this happens only in some servers, but not on others. So I'm guessing is somehow related to the PHP config. I have this code:

```
$j = 0 ;
                    for($m = $days - 1; $m >= 0 ; $m--){
                        $time1 = strtotime('-'.$m.' DAY');
                        $date_day = date('Y-m-d', $time1) ;

                        $$items_var[$j] = new stdClass();

                        $j++;
                    }
```

The value of $days is 7. So this is for loop where $m goes from 6 to 0. well.. it should be. it starts ok, it does 6,5,4,3... and then it crashes. usually the error I get is
**Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

so, at some point (and it looks random, because in some servers is after the second iteration), the $m becomes an object...!!

this is somehow related to that assignation you see on the code:

$$items_var[$j] = new stdClass();

Yes, that's a double $$. I have a variable $items_var which value is "items". Therefore I'm trying to create this new stdClass() in an array called $items.

this is what's messing the code, but I don't know why. If I remove this assignation, the code works. the $m goes from 6 to 0. but for some reason, some PHP installations are messing this up and this line of code CHANGES the value of $m to an object.

I am clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's EXACTLY this:

> Yes, that's a double $$. I have a variable $items_var which value is "items".

That means you have:

```
$items_var = 'items';
```

And you're using that string as an array:

```
$$items_var[$j] = new stdClass();
```

When `$j` = 3, you're effectively running

```
$m = new stdClass();
```

and have now **overwritten** your `for` loop variable with an object. On the NEXT iteration, you end up doing

```
stdClass() >= 0
```

and produce your exact error.

This is exactly WHY you should **NEVER** use variable-variables. You end up with stupid/impossibly difficult-to-debug errors like this.

---

comment followup:

PHP allows strings to be treated as arrays of characters:

```
$foo = 'abcdefgh';
echo $foo[3] // outputs 'd'
```

Variable variables take the contents of a variable, and use it as the name of some OTHER variable:

```
$bar = 'hi mom';
$foo = 'bar';

echo $foo;  // outputs 'bar'
echo $$foo; // outputs 'hi mom'
```

So given:

```
$items_vars = 'items';
$j = 3;
```

This sequence occurs:

```
$$items_vars[$j] = new stdClass();
 ^-------------^
        |
$   'items'[3]   = new stdClass();
        |
$       m        = new stdClass();

$m = new stdClass();
```

and boom, your `$m` that you're using in `for($m=....)` is now trashed.

---

code deconstruction. If you pull apart your loop and write it out longhand:

```
$items_vars = 'items';
$j = 0;
for($m = $days - 1; $m >= 0 ; $m--){
    $$items_var[$j] = new stdClass();
```

You end up doing this:

```
               $$items_vars[$j]     = new StdClass:
j = 0; m =6    ${'items'[0]}  -> $i = new stdClas();
j = 1; m = 5   ${'items'[1]}  -> $t = new stdClass();
j = 2; m = 4   ${'items'[2]}  -> $e = new stdClass();
j = 3; m = 3   ${'items'[3]}  -> $m // BOOM
```

You're not putting your new stdClass objects into an array. Your variable-variable is building SINGLE LETTER variable names, and putting a stdClass into each of them. If you want to store your new classes in an array, you'd need something more like

```
array_push($$items_var, new stdClass());
```

which would execute as

```
array_push($items, new stdClass());
```

Comment: Hopefully he is not switch from PHP < 7 to PHP >=7 ;)  That makes it even more critical: `$$items_var[$j]`   `${$items_var[$j]}` vs `${$items_var}[$j]`

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer... but I still don't fully understand...:

Comment: $$items_var[$j] is not "equivalent" to saying $items[$j] ? why this happens when $j=3 ? besides that.. using this syntax you mention ${$items_var}[$j] would solve the problem? the thing is that I reeeaaalllyy would need to use variable-variables.. because otherwise my code will have thousands of lines instead of just a few...

Comment: Very nice explanation!

Comment: No, you don't need "thousands of lines". But you're NOT building an array of dates, you're building a bunch of VARIABLES with dates.